# PowerShell How to access a file from a network drive?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, drive

I have a Script that reads a log file and creates a text file with some output taken from the log file.

The script works and it takes the right log file as long as it is on my C:\ drive.

The Original File is located on the network drive called s:\ but if I want to take this log by entering the whole path where the file lives I get the error that >> The Drive wasnt found and that a Drive called S does not exist.

How can I connect to a network drive?

```
$inVar = Select-String -path C:\Dev\Script\Ldorado.log  -pattern "IN:"  -WORKS
$inVar = Select-String -path S:\Lic_Debug\Ldorado.log  -pattern "IN:" - Does not work!
```

Comment: Did you try to use an UNC path?

Comment: nope can you show me how ?

Comment: Is `S:` the drive visible normally (i.e. in Windows Explorer)?  Are you running the script elevated (i.e. as and admin user)?  It might be that you're hitting this by-design limitation: [Mapped drives are not available from an elevated prompt ...](https://support.microsoft.com/bg-bg/help/3035277/mapped-drives-are-not-available-from-an-elevated-prompt-when-uac-is-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the Answers - I actually managed it by changing the Path name in \fs01\ because that represents the S:\ and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try prepending the path with "FileSystem::" i.e. -path FileSystem::s:\Lic_Debug\Ldorado.log

This ensures your script uses the FileSystem provider which should correctly recognise the drive.